# Java lwgjl2 change cursor image

Tags: java, cursor, mouse, lwjgl

I want to change the Cursor image in Java in my LWJGL project. But so far i only found solutions to do it with a GLFW Window, which i am not using.

I have really no idea how, since any attempt failed.
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LWJGL 2.9.1

```
Cursor cursor = new Cursor(int width, int height, int xHotspot, int yHotspot, int numImages, IntBuffer images, IntBuffer delays);
Mouse.setNativeCursor(cursor);
```

Also, LWJGL 2 is not supported anymore and you should start using LWJGL 3.
https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/1.2.-Why-a-new-version

Comment: When i try this method, i have to use an IntBuffer. And everytime i use a pngImage and convert it to an intBuffer the Image is either veryverySmall and totally disorted. or i get an error like this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Number of remaining buffer elements is 68, must be at least 144. Because at most 144 elements can be returned, a buffer with at least 144 elements is required,

Comment: I cannot tell what is wrong, when I do not see the code.